# How to set Selected value for Kendo combobox in javaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Combobox and i want Set Selected Value in javaScript

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
.Name("EditSelectComidityN")
.Filter("contains")
.Placeholder("Select Comidity...")
.DataValueField("ComidityId")
.DataTextField("ComidityName")
.HtmlAttributes(new { tabindex = 1 })
.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Cmlist"])
.Height(300)
.HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "EditSelectComidityN" })
)
```

it's my Combobox and i Trys these Codes and don't work

```
var combobox = $("#EditSelectComidityN").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.value(4);
```

and

```
var cbx = $("#EditSelectComidityN").data("kendoComboBox")
cbx.select(4);
```

what i Have to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
var combobox = $("#EditSelectComidityN").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.value(4);
```

its works